# Optimizing retrieval of search results for aggregate

Tags: php, mysql, performance, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11 and trying to speed up the retrieval of model data for the client application. I've tried three approaches, each of them being roughly the same speed which has me stumped.

For this example, I am retrieving Purchase Orders along with their Items and all associated Address records. The data is spread across three tables: `purchase_orders`, `purchase_order_items` and `purchase_order_addresses`.

The schema is as you would expect:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE purchase_orders;
+--------------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type                     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(11)                  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| purchase_order_num | varchar(250)             | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |

mysql> DESCRIBE purchase_ord_contents;
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                                  | Null | Key | Default      | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)                               | NO   | PRI | NULL         | auto_increment |
| purchase_order_id | int(11)                               | NO   | MUL | NULL         |                |
| sku               | varchar(250)                          | NO   | MUL | NULL         |                |
| name              | varchar(250)                          | YES  |     | NULL         |                |


mysql> DESCRIBE purchase_order_addresses;
+-------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                               | Null | Key | Default     | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)                            | NO   | PRI | NULL        | auto_increment |
| purchase_order_id | int(11)                            | NO   | MUL | NULL        |                |
| label             | varchar(255)                       | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
| address_line_1    | varchar(255)                       | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
....etc.
```

**Method 1 (findDependentRowset) - 1000 records in ~12 seconds**

```
foreach($this->fetchSearchResults($searchParams) as $orderRow){
    $orderData = $orderRow->toArray();

    // both of these methods call findDependentRowset
    $orderData['items'] = $orderRow->getItems()->toArray();
    $orderData['addresses'] = $orderRow->getAddresses()->toArray();

    $results[] = $orderData;
}
```

**Method 2 (nested SQL queries, 1000 records ~9 seconds)**

```
foreach($this->fetchSearchResults($searchParams) as $orderRow){
    $orderData = $orderRow->toArray();

    $orderData['items'] = self::$items->fetchAll(['purchase_order_id = ?' => $row->id])->toArray();
    $orderData['addresses'] = self::$addresses->fetchAll(['purchase_order_id = ?' => $row->id])->toArray();

    $results[] = $orderData;
}
```

**Method 3 (minimize queries and sort data, 1000 records ~10 seconds)**

```
$orderRows   = $this->fetchSearchResults($searchParams);
$orderIds    = array_column($orderRows->toarray(), 'id');
$itemRows    = self::$items->fetchAll(['purchase_order_id IN (?)' => array_values($orderIds)]);
$addressRows = self::$addresses->fetchAll(['purchase_order_id IN (?)' => array_values($orderIds)]);

$searchResults = array_map(function($order) use($itemsRows, $addressRows) {
    $order['contents'] = array_filter($itemsRows->toArray(), function($itemRow) use($order){
        return ($itemRow['purchase_order_id'] === $order['id']);
    });

    $order['addresses'] = array_filter($addressRows->toArray(), function($addressRow) use($order){
        return ($addressRow['purchase_order_id'] === $order['id']);
    });

    return $order;
}, $orderRows->toArray());
```

I was surprised to see that sorting the data set using `array_*` functions was slower than "method 2" despite eliminating ~2000 queries and barely faster than using Zend's `findDependentRowset`

How can I speed these queries up? Would there be a way to, in a single query, retrieve the Order along with all of its Items and Addresses?

Comment: where is the hole Query , and the table create / structure and a explain of the query

Comment: @BerndBuffen I added the schema. Queries are built via Zend's query builder

Comment: can you please add also the query and the result from   EXPLAIN (your query) to see which index are used or not

Comment: I don't see anything like a `JOIN`, which would be the 'right' way to get all the data -- with a _single_ `SELECT`.  I'll second @BerndBuffen's request for `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (not `DESCRIBE`), the actual `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  (I get irritated with 3rd party software that obfuscates the SQL, making it difficult to optimize.)

Comment: I've decided to just load the "many" side of the one-to-many association as-needed by the client application, rather than at the time of load.